# Converting escaped XML entities back into UTF-8

Tags: ruby, escaping, xml-entities

So I've got this UTF-8 string in an XML file:

```
Horrible place. ☠☠☠
```

And when I feed it to an external application, the funny characters come back escaped as XML entities:

```
Horrible place. &#x2620;&#x2620;&#x2620;
```

In Ruby, how do I convert that string back to UTF-8?  There's probably a really easy solution for this, but I'm unable to find anything in the standard libraries; eg. `CGI.unescapeHTML` (which work nicely for things like `&gt;`) seem to ignore them completely.

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > CGI.unescapeHTML('&gt;')
 => ">" 
ree-1.8.7-2010.02 > CGI.unescapeHTML('&#x2620;')
 => "&#x2620;"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since it's XML encoded I'd go for an XML parser:

```
require 'nokogiri'

frag = 'Horrible place. &#x2620;&#x2620;&#x2620;'
doc = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(frag)
puts doc.text
# >> Horrible place. ☠☠☠
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  I was calling `doc.to_xml`, which retained the entities.

Comment: Yes, it will because `to_xml` creates an XML representation.

Answer (score 2):

`CGI.unescapeHTML` works just fine; the console you are using is probably unable to display the unicode character.

Try this and it should work fine:

```
File.open("d:\\11.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write(CGI.unescapeHTML('&#x2620;')) } # => ☠
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the file says "&#x2620;" and so does splitting the output string into bytes: `CGI.unescapeHTML('&#x2620;').bytes.each {|b| print "#{b} "} => 38 35 120 50 54 50 48 59`.  This is in Rails 2.3, what version are you using?

Comment: That's weird. I used ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32].