# Ruby string force encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I force encode this: `Al-F\u0026#257;ti\u0026#293;ah` to `Al-Fātiĥah`

I tried `.encode!('UTF-16', :undef => :replace, :invalid => :replace, :replace => "")` and `force_encoding("UTF-8")` with no luck

Answer (score 1):

That text seems to include HTML or XML entities.

Try

```
require "cgi/util"
CGI.unescapeHTML("Al-F\u0026#257;ti\u0026#293;ah")
```

or

```
# gem install nokogiri
require "nokogiri"
Nokogiri::XML.fragment("Al-F\u0026#257;ti\u0026#293;ah").text
```

See: [Converting escaped XML entities back into UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559104/converting-escaped-xml-entities-back-into-utf-8)